# Paypal API used on Prestashop

Tags: paypal, prestashop

Is it applicable to use the same Paypal API username, password and signature in 2 different installation of Prestashop on different domain and hosting? Or is it to be a unique  Paypal API username, password and signature for each Paypal module for every Prestashop ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes
2. No.

Your Paypal credentials are no tied to your domain or hosting, they just give you access to Paypal service.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Appreciated.